# Flipping numpy array axes based on values in second array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras, flip

Currently writing a custom data generator for Keras and I'm looking to randomly flip a numpy input array during training for data augmentation purposes.

- `X`: input array of shape `(batchsize, y_dim, x_dim)`
- `to_flip`: boolean array of shape `(batchsize, X_rank)` that describes which axes to flip

For example:

```
X = [[[0, 1],
      [2, 3]],
     [[4, 5],
      [6, 7]]]

to_flip = [[0, 1],
           [1, 0]]

flipped_X = [[[1, 0],
              [3, 2]],
             [[6, 7],
              [4, 5]]]
```

or any combination of axes (both/no axes flipped).
I couldn't figure out how to use either `np.flip` or advanced indexing (e.g. `X[::-1]`) by themselves to get this effect. Ideally, I'd be able to find a solution that could be applied to the whole batch without explicit loops, because I believe that such a solution would be faster.

The best solution I have currently is:

```py
def flip_axes(an_input, axes_to_flip):
    axis_inds_to_flip = np.where(axes_to_flip.reshape(-1))[0]
    return np.flip(an_input, axis_inds_to_flip)[None, ...]

flipped_X = np.concatenate([flip_axes(an_input, axes_to_flip) 
                            for an_input, axes_to_flip 
                            in zip(X, to_flip)], axis=0)
```

Anyone have any thoughts? Would this indeed be quicker than what I've written here?

edit: I've revised my solution so that it executes and I've added my motivation for the question.

Comment: Could you please explain how you flip `X` w.r.t. `[[0, 1], [1, 0]]`?

Comment: @Ehsan Row 0 says that 0th matrix in the batch should be not be flipped over the 0th axis and should be flipped over the 1st axis. Row 1 says that the 1st matrix should be flipped over the 0th axis and should not be flipped over the 1st axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using python indexing as follows,

```py
flipped_X = []
for sample, flip in zip(X, to_flip):
  flipped = [*sample]                          # Generate a copy of x
  if flip[0]:                                  # if flip[0] is 1
    flipped = flipped[::-1]                    # Flip matrix vertically
  if flip[1]:                                  # if flip[1] is 1
    flipped = [elem[::-1] for elem in flipped] # Flip elements to flip horizontally
  flipped_X.append(flipX)                      # Finally append to result
print(flipped_X)
```

Will output:

```
[[[1, 0], [3, 2]], [[6, 7], [4, 5]]]
```

**EDIT:** Using numpy you can achieve the same result with `np.flip(m, axis)`, where `m` will be each matrix in `X` and `axis` will be a tuple of the indexes to flip. For example:

`to_flip = [[0,0], [1,0], [0,1], [1,1]]`

so the indexes will be

`[[], [0], [1], [0,1]]`

```py
# Get indexes to flip at each sample
flip_idxes = map(lambda flip: [idx for idx, x in enumerate(flip) if x], to_flip)
# Flip samples
flipped_X = np.array([np.flip(sample, indexes) for sample, indexes in zip(X, flip_idxes)])
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation of the code you have written...

Comment: Done @Yatin! Thanks for your suggestion, hope it has become clear.

Comment: @JuliánEstebanSalomónTorres Thanks for the input, although I don't see how either of these solutions is markedly different than the list comprehension solution I've posted in the question. In the first proposed solution, you've simply expanded the for loop and hard coded the indices, then used a conditional, list comprehension, and slicing to flip. In the second solution, you've replaced my np.where with a lambda that does the same, and then used a list comprehension with flip. My intention was to find a solution that potentially avoided explicit loops and could be applied to the whole batch.

Comment: Excuse me, I hadn't seen the edits you've made to your question, I've answered the initial question, but I don't have any idea to the new approach you'd given to the question.